# Help with recursion and returning value

Tags: c#, .net, string, recursion

This is an extension of a previously posted question. I'm trying to recursively build a string. I need to change the function below to do this - each recursion of the function generates the desired string, but I need to concat these together and return the whole string. 'related' is passed into the function as an empty string and I thought the way I was using string.Format would append each recursion to the 'related' string? Apparently not.

Not sure how...

```
private string getRelatedNews(Taxonomy taxData, string related, string contentTitle)
{
    foreach (TaxonomyItemData item in taxData.TaxonomyItems)
        {
            if (taxData.TaxonomyName.Equals(contentTitle) && taxData.TaxonomyItemCount != 0)
            {
                related = string.Format("{0}<li><a href='{1}'\">{2}</a></li>", related, item.Link, item.Name);
            }                   
        }
    // Show all its sub categories
    foreach (TaxonomyData cat in taxData.Taxonomy)
        {   
            getRelatedNews(cat, related, contentTitle);
        }

    return(related);

}
```

Comment: One issue with this is that you will be creating numerous strings that are thrown away (increasing pressure on the GC).  Look into using StringBuilder to build a string only once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
foreach (TaxonomyData cat in taxData.Taxonomy)
    {   
        getRelatedNews(cat, related, contentTitle);
    }
```

should be

```
foreach (TaxonomyData cat in taxData.Taxonomy)
    {   
        related = getRelatedNews(cat, related, contentTitle);
    }
```

because strings are immutable.

Comment: Bingo. Gives exactly the result I expected. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well try this...

```
related = getRelatedNews(cat, related, contentTitle);
```

I am not sure about your logic and flow of the program... then also I think recursive function must be called like this....

```
private string getRelatedNews(Taxonomy taxData, string related, string contentTitle)
{
    foreach (TaxonomyItemData item in taxData.TaxonomyItems)
        {
            if (taxData.TaxonomyName.Equals(contentTitle) && taxData.TaxonomyItemCount != 0)
            {
                related = string.Format("{0}<li><a href='{1}'\">{2}</a></li>", related, item.Link, item.Name);
            }                   
        }
    // Show all its sub categories
    foreach (TaxonomyData cat in taxData.Taxonomy)
        {   
            related = getRelatedNews(cat, related, contentTitle);
        }

    return(related);

}
```

Comment: he is alreadt concatenating using string.Format, you should not be doing related = related + string.Format....